# I can't open a x86 file (16.04)

Tags: 16.04

So I was trying to download baldi basics then when I try to open the game (.x86) it says cannot open file.Even when I try to right click and go to permisson it is blank so I can't turn on execute when opened.

This is where you download: https://mystman12.itch.io/baldis-basics

it is not a installation from ubuntu.

Please Help!

Comment: Hi Alex!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  We need a bit more information.  Where did you download the .x86 file from?  Does it say it's for installation on Ubuntu? Please edit your question to include these details.  Thanks!

Comment: @tudor I just included the download link!

Answer (score 1):

That application is not a Ubuntu application or even a Debian package.  It is a Linux ELF file.  (This is why someone gave you a downvote and this question will most likely be shelved.)

**These applications are dangerous to run**, because you can't verify they do what they intended.  Without proper packaging, there is **no way** to verify:

- that there is source code to verify
- that the code does as you expect
- that the application doesn't break your system, or delete, corrupt, or publish your private data
- that the application doesn't insert a temporary or permanent security hole into your system

*However*, even with that caveat ELF files refer directly to libraries in the system.  If you don't have that library *in that location*, then the application still won't run.  If you have the library in the right location, then the symbols may mismatch.

Nonetheless, if you *still* want to avoid all these warnings, then by all means `chmod u+x` the file and that will be the only possible way for it to run.